# Dynamic BorderLayout with user input / Event Listener

Tags: java, swing, addeventlistener

I am new to Event Listeners. I found this exercise. My goal is to change `BorderLayout` with the user input. I tried using `DocumentListener` and `ActionListener` but I couldn't make it work. Here is what I could code:

```
public class Eventlistenertest extends JFrame {

    public Eventlistenertest(){
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(i, j));    // here is i and j.

        p1.add(new JButton("East"), BorderLayout.EAST);
        p1.add(new JButton("South"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        p1.add(new JButton("West"), BorderLayout.WEST);
        p1.add(new JButton("North"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p1.add(new JButton("Center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Container of BorderLayout"));

        JTextField VGap = new JTextField(35);
        JTextField HGap = new JTextField(35);

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 20));
        p2.add(new JLabel("HGap"));
        p2.add(HGap);
        p2.add(new JLabel("VGap"));
        p2.add(VGap);
        p2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("BorderLayout Properties"));

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));
        add(p1);
        add(p2);

        int i =Integer.parseInt(HGap.getText());
        int j =Integer.parseInt(VGap.getText());   
    }

    /** Main method */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Eventlistenertest frame = new Eventlistenertest();
        frame.setTitle("ShowBorderLayout");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I need to have `i` and `j` zero at the beginning, and change them after the `JTextField` input. How can I do this?

Comment: "I found this exercise" Which exercise? "I couldn't make it work" What are you trying to make it do?

Comment: You'll need to reflow and relayout the whole Frame after the input... enjoy your taste of swing

Comment: I am trying to change BorderLayout(i, j) and i and j will be user input.

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Essentially, one way is to add a `ActionListener` to your fields and when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, up the layout

```
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int vgap = 0;
            int hgap = 0;
            if (VGap.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
                try {
                    vgap = Integer.parseInt(VGap.getText());
                } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid number for vgap");
                }
            }
            if (HGap.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
                try {
                    hgap = Integer.parseInt(HGap.getText());
                } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid number for vgap");
                }
            }
            borderLayout.setHgap(hgap);
            borderLayout.setVgap(vgap);
            p1.revalidate();
        }

    };

    VGap.addActionListener(listener);
    HGap.addActionListener(listener);
```

There is one requirement, the instance of `BorderLayout` which you first apply to `p1` MUST be the same instance that you update.

You could use a `DocumentListener`, but the process becomes much more complicated

Comment: I will try it, thanks.